# Error while trying to make AVD work

Tags: eclipse, android-sdk

I managed to install the latest version of eclipse and make it work correctly, along with the SDK manager. I downloaded all the necessary bits. When I attempt to run the AVD (Android Virtual Device) Manager, all is well. It reads the builds of the Android API and allows me to create the emulator profile but when I attempt to run the emulator i get the following error:

```
Failed to start emulator: Cannot run program 
"/opt/SDK//tools/emulator": error=2, No such file or directory
```

The problem is obviously the extra slash. I have ensured that there is no trailing slash in the SDK path (in the Eclipse prefs) and I cant think of where its coming from... any ideas?

**EDIT 3**

the following commands have been run:

```
cromwell@Terminal-0:~$ sudo chown -R root:eclipse /opt/*
cromwell@Terminal-0:~$ sudo chmod -R 775 /opt/*
cromwell@Terminal-0:~$ sudo chmod +x /opt/*
```

**EDIT 4**
if it makes a difference, it was a manual install (probably not done correctly) i copied the files (For the SDK and eclipse) to /opt and ran the EDIT 3 commands. The JDK was installed using a PPA but there is also a copy under /opt/eclipse/jre... the following 2 pages aided me in installation:

http://www.webupd8.org/2012/09/install-oracle-java-8-in-ubuntu-via-ppa.html
https://wiki.ubuntu.com/fballem/Software%2012.04#Eclipse

im also using the latest Kubuntu 13.1 64 bit... could that be part of the problem?

**EDIT**

This is the output from the console

```
cromwell@Terminal-0:~$ sudo /opt/SDK/tools/emulator
[sudo] password for cromwell: 
sudo: unable to execute /opt/SDK/tools/emulator: No such file or directory
```

I feel like there's something funny (not funny "ha-ha") going on since there IS in fact such a file in that directory

**EDIT 2**

Console output in response to a comment

```
cromwell@Terminal-0:~$ ls -l /opt/SDK/tools/
total 18272
-rwxrwxr-x 1 root eclipse     323 Mar 21 15:17 adb_has_moved.txt
-rwxrwxr-x 1 root eclipse    3498 Mar 21 15:17 android
drwxrwxr-x 2 root eclipse    4096 Mar 21 15:17 ant
drwxrwxr-x 3 root eclipse    4096 Mar 21 15:17 apps
-rwxrwxr-x 1 root eclipse    3286 Mar 21 15:17 ddms
-rwxrwxr-x 1 root eclipse   49112 Mar 21 15:17 dmtracedump
-rwxrwxr-x 1 root eclipse    1940 Mar 21 15:17 draw9patch
-rwxrwxr-x 1 root eclipse   37338 Mar 21 15:17 emulator
-rwxrwxr-x 1 root eclipse 2854385 Mar 21 15:17 emulator64-arm
-rwxrwxr-x 1 root eclipse 2884527 Mar 21 15:17 emulator64-mips
-rwxrwxr-x 1 root eclipse 2955802 Mar 21 15:17 emulator64-x86
-rwxrwxr-x 1 root eclipse 2706381 Mar 21 15:17 emulator-arm
-rwxrwxr-x 1 root eclipse 2679855 Mar 21 15:17 emulator-mips
-rwxrwxr-x 1 root eclipse 2809004 Mar 21 15:17 emulator-x86
-rwxrwxr-x 1 root eclipse  170613 Mar 21 15:17 etc1tool
-rwxrwxr-x 1 root eclipse    3464 Mar 21 15:17 hierarchyviewer
-rwxrwxr-x 1 root eclipse   10566 Mar 21 15:17 hprof-conv
-rwxrwxr-x 1 root eclipse    1845 Mar 21 15:17 jobb
drwxrwxr-x 8 root eclipse    4096 Mar 21 15:17 lib
-rwxrwxr-x 1 root eclipse    2046 Mar 21 15:17 lint
-rwxrwxr-x 1 root eclipse   11819 Mar 21 15:17 mksdcard
-rwxrwxr-x 1 root eclipse    1293 Mar 21 15:17 monitor
-rwxrwxr-x 1 root eclipse    3176 Mar 21 15:17 monkeyrunner
-rwxrwxr-x 1 root eclipse  695122 Mar 21 15:17 NOTICE.txt
drwxrwxr-x 7 root eclipse    4096 Mar 21 15:17 proguard
-rwxrwxr-x 1 root eclipse      70 Mar 21 15:17 source.properties
-rwxrwxr-x 1 root eclipse  681566 Mar 21 15:17 sqlite3
drwxrwxr-x 2 root eclipse    4096 Mar 21 15:17 support
drwxrwxr-x 6 root eclipse    4096 Mar 21 15:17 templates
-rwxrwxr-x 1 root eclipse    3219 Mar 21 15:17 traceview
-rwxrwxr-x 1 root eclipse    3054 Mar 21 15:17 uiautomatorviewer
-rwxrwxr-x 1 root eclipse   65552 Mar 21 15:17 zipalign
```

.....

```
cromwell@Terminal-0:~$ ls -l /opt/SDK/tools/emulator
-rwxrwxr-x 1 root eclipse 37338 Mar 21 15:17 /opt/SDK/tools/emulator
```

Comment: I'm not sure that the extra slash is to blame. I don't know why, but bash is okay with it. For example, try `cd /usr//local`. Are you 100% sure that there is a file there? Can you post the output of `ls -l /opt/SDK/tools/emulator`?

Comment: @Sparhawk 110% sure... it was a manual install (which i spent a good while on)... check the edit...

Comment: @Sparhawk "emulator" is a binary...

Comment: Very odd. A couple of comments… `emulator` has `o+x` permissions, so you don't have to execute it as root. Just in case it's useful, can you try `/opt/SDK/tools/emulator` (probably not)? Also, I get slightly different errors when I try and execute non-existent files. `$ ./foobar` `bash: ./foobar: No such file or directory` `$ sudo ./foobar` `sudo: ./foobar: command not found`. I never get `unable to execute`. It might be irrelevant, and dependent on your shell, or it perhaps might suggest that the error message is imprecise, and there's an internal bug instead?

Comment: @Sparhawk same result without sudo... hmmm

Comment: Hmmm indeed. Sorry, I'm out of ideas. Hopefully someone else can help.

Comment: @Sparhawk thanks =) i appreciate the assistance